# Making mirrored object a real object with mesh

Tags: mirror

I can't figure out how to make your mirror into actual mesh. I want to be able to make my mirror into mesh so I can move one side of my object without moving the other side.

Comment: Apply the modifier (click on the little down arrow on the right side).

Comment: You can also click anywhere in the mirror modifier panel so that it's hilighted with a blue line and use Ctrl-A to apply it.